# access permissions vary to same file based on program

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems

I have an odd case where cat can read a file, but another program cannot. Looking at the two program calls using strace, the open calls look like:

```
/home/ubuntu/dibas/bin/guppi_daq
open("/home/ubuntu/dibas/etc/config/guppi_threads.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)


/bin/cat /home/ubuntu/dibas/etc/config/guppi_threads.conf
open("/home/ubuntu/dibas/etc/config/guppi_threads.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Both commands are run as root, file permissions are 777. 
Filesystem is a local ext4 filesystem.

How can this be??

Comment: Note that a program can change its effective UID whilst it is running.  `cat` will not do it but we cannot tell much about `guppi_daq`.  Then I would be concerned about the permissions of all directories: `/home/ubuntu/dibas/etc/config`, if any of them has no global execute permissions it will not be traversed by a non-priviledged user.

Comment: Are there any extended permission on the system?  Add the output of `ls -l /home/ubuntu/dibas/etc/config/guppi_threads.conf` to your question.

Comment: Does `guppi_daq` run with lowered privileges? Are there applicable SELinux or AppArmor rules?

Comment: No dropping of privileges, and the file permissions were set to rwxrwxrwx.The system was not running SELinux, however, the apparmor comment  is interesting. I'll be sure to check that.